# how to create custom contact form in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

This might be duplicate question. How to create custom contact form in Joomla and send an filled form on email?

There could be many ways like create an `custom html` but which is the appropriate and easy way to do it?

Please give me some threads or links

Comment: You should look around first before asking a question that can simply be answered with a 10 second search......http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fantastic extension called Chrono Forms. 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508

You can download it for free for any version of Joomla:
http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/9-chronoforms.html

The extension comes with video tutorials which will guide you step by step, easy to follow, and good support. Just browse the www.chronoengine.com website, or ask questions in their forum if you run into any complications while creating your form.

I've created many forms using this extension, contact forms, newsletter subscription forms and so on.
The extension offers high customization, and it also has Captcha, recaptha or honey trap options to avoid spam upon submission.